# Semantics for set theory

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Every logic book I’ve ever come across, when talking about the semantics of first-order logic, defines concepts like structures and interpretations where the most important element is a set called the “domain of discourse” or the “universe”. Everything is then based on this set. This works very nicely for number theory, but what is the universe of set theory? The set of all sets does not exist. So how do you define all the concepts of semantics?

Comment: Not a set theorist. But I believe the "set" in [natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language) is not the same as *sets* in *set* theory. I have never seen people write "a 'set' called the 'domain of discourse'" but just "domain of discourse".

Comment: Well, if you read about semantics of first-order languages, the domain of discourse is defined as a set and that set is used to define the mapping between the terms of the language and the objects they refer to.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Enderton - A mathematical introduction to logic, Mendelson - Introduction to mathematicsl logic, Tourlakis - Lectures in logic and set theory.... any book I pick talks about a set D upon which structures and/or interpretations are based.

Comment: The concept of semantics seem to still be defined just fine. An interpretation of a language is a set along with interpretation of the symbols as relations or functions on that set. There's no difference simply because we choose our language to be the (very simple!) language of set theory. There are set-sized models of set theory (say, ZFC), even countable models (provided ZFC is consistent, of course, which isn't provable in ZFC because of the incompleteness theorem).... no need for these things to include "all sets".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be rigorous about this you need to understand the distinction between the [metalanguage](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/) in which we are reasoning about the semantics and the object languages whose semantics we are reasoning about. The statement that the set of all sets does not exist is relative to the closure properties that we require of the set of all sets: we may assume stronger closure properties in our metalanguage (e.g., the existence of [Grothendieck universes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) containing any set) than we do in our object language (e.g., closure under the axioms of ZF (Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory)). Note that the metalanguage and the object language may have exactly the same syntax: it is the way we are using them and the axioms that we assume in them that matters.

For many purposes in set theory, particularly independence results, it is enough to formulate results predicated on the existence of a model of set theory. E.g., to prove that the axiom of choice $AC$ is independent of the other axioms of $ZF$, we have to show that if $ZF$ has a model, then so does $ZFC = ZF+AC$. This statement does not assume the existence of a model of either $ZF$ or $ZFC$.

Likewise, the completeness theorem states that for any theory $T$ and any sentence $\phi$, if $T \models \phi$ (i.e., if $\phi$ holds in every model of $T$) then $T \vdash \phi$ (i.e., $\phi$ can be derived from $T$ using first-order logic). ZFC can prove this for all $T$, including $T = ZFC$, but that doesn't imply that a model for $ZFC$ can be constructed in $ZFC$.

Note also the assertion $T \models \phi$ in the statement of the completeness theorem is about all models of $T$, not just some chosen standard model with a given universe of discourse. Taking $T$ to be $PA$ (Peano arithmetic), we know from the incompleteness theorem that there are sentences $\phi$ (such as a sentence asserting that $PA$ is consistent) such that $PA \not\vdash \phi$, even though $\phi$ is true if we restrict our universe of discourse to the natural numbers. The completeness theorem then tells us that $PA$ has a model in which $\lnot\phi$ holds.

Comment: I think my expectations are too high. You are way more knowledgeable than me and I had never heard of Grothendieck universes. However, what I had in mind goes along these lines. Most people accept ZFC as a foundation for mathematics, so the metalanguage, like any other language, should be based on ZFC. But when we prove that FOL is sound and complete with that metalanguage, how can we say it is true for the language of ZFC itself if we cannot define the domain of discourse? And if we need an alternative language to overcome this, then maybe that should be at the foundations of mathematics?

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit. I hope that helps. I think your main problem is your notion that "everything is based on a [fixed standard universe of discourse]": a quick look through the contents list of Mendelson's book for example doesn't justify this: in only a few places does the notion of standard model play an essential role.